# mysql group by email address with count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am trying to write a query - I have a 1000 users on a data base and want to find the ones with more than 1 entry

```
SELECT * , COUNT( * ) AS number 
FROM  `users` 
WHERE  `id` >309438 
GROUP BY email and `number` > 1
```

I don't think i am a million miles away..

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS number 
FROM users 
WHERE id > 309438 
GROUP BY email 
HAVING number > 1
```

Comment: A note to @LeBlaireau: Jurgen's query will give you the emai accounts with more than one user associated to it.  if you need to know users with more than one email account then just replace email by 'id' in both occurrences.

Comment: I think number should go into where condition becuase it is not placed within any aggregate function.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: No, it should not. And `number` is aggregated. It is `count(*)`

Comment: ohhh. You are absolutly right. I haven't see that. My bad.